# CSS : Image scaling animation inside of an SVG not working in Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, scaling

I am trying to create a scale animation of an image inside of an svg tag. 
It works well in Chrome but in Firefox, the image also moves to the side and bottom in addition to being scaled.

This is the simple code I've created to illustrate the problem :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        @keyframes pulse_animation {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1, 1);
                transform-origin: center;
            }
            50% {
                transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
                transform-origin: center;
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(1, 1);
                transform-origin: center;
            }
        }

        .pulse {
            animation: pulse_animation 5s infinite;
        }
    </style
</head>
<body>

<svg width="566" height="203">
    <image x="229.2736842105263" y="170" width="30" height="30"
           xlink:href=[someimage]
           class="pulse"></image>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!